Inner cavity region
I have a cloud of points with a cavity inside. Given a reference point inside the cavity, I want to approximate cavity region with (somewhat convex) MeshRegion that is allowed to have cloud points on the boundary, but not inside it. For some reason I can't find any standard procedures for this problem.
Here is a function to generate test data:
ClearAll[generateFakeData];
generateFakeData[d_, n_, m_] := Block[
    {points, region},
    points = RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, {n, d}] ;
    region = ConvexHullRegion[RandomSample[points, m]] ;
    points = RandomReal[{-1.0, 1.0}, {n, d}] ;
    points = Select[points, Not @* RegionMember[region]];
    {points, region}
];

and examples for 2D and 3D
d = 2 ;
n = 10000 ;
m = 100 ;
{points, region} = generateFakeData[d,n,m] ;
Total[Boole[RegionMember[region][points]]]
Show[
    RegionPlot[RegionBoundary@region, PlotStyle->Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]], 
    ListPlot[points,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Blue],
    PlotRange->All
]


d = 3 ;
n = 10000 ;
m = 100 ;
{points, region} = generateFakeData[d,n,m] ;
Total[Boole[RegionMember[region][points]]]
Show[
    RegionPlot3D[RegionBoundary@region, PlotStyle->Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]], 
    ListPointPlot3D[points, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Blue],
    PlotRange -> All
]


My actual data is in 2D or 4D and cloud points are quite dense around the cavity with a fractal boundary structure (like the inside of Mandelbrot set in 2D). I have a couple functions to estimate the inner region for 2D, but they do not work for higher dimensions.
An example with actual data in 2D (reduced number of cloud point), the inner point here is zero:
(* ~ 7.5M CSV *)
data = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kctdnf5ike59xvyfb7ywu/data.csv?rlkey=jm1vn7qqqtlk3geurkgr1u1zu&st=0ljvl2z4&dl=1", "CSV"] ;
plot = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]



concave = ConcaveHullMesh[points]; regs = ConnectedMeshComponents[RegionBoundary[concave]]; Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]], EdgeForm[],    regs[[-1]], Blue, Point@points}] ?

@cvgmt, thanks, I ' ll test your suggestion later, meanwhile I do not see how the reference point which should be inside is used

@cvgmt, your suggestion requires ConcaveHullMesh[data, 0.01] for the actual 2d and I'm not sure whether it parameter be selected automatically

Edit
Here is a solution that works in ND by filling the cavity with balls. Geometric ops (union, measure and etc) can be applied to generated balls specified by center and radius.
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
<< CCompilerDriver` ;

SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> {"ParallelThreadNumber" -> 32}] ;
Compiler`$CCompilerOptions = {"SystemCompileOptions" -> "-O3 -ffast-math -march=native"} ;

ClearAll[isPointInsideNBall] ;
isPointInsideNBall = With[
    {epsilon=10.0^-9},
    Compile[
        {{point, _Real, 1}, {center, _Real, 1}, {radius, _Real}},
        Sqrt[Total[(point - center)^2]] < radius + epsilon,
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
        Parallelization -> True,
        CompilationTarget -> "C",
        CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True},
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
] ;    

ClearAll[generateRandomPointsOnNBall] ;
generateRandomPointsOnNBall = Compile[
    {{n, _Integer}, {center, _Real, 1}, {radius, _Real}},
    Block[
        {dimensions, directions},
        dimensions = Length[center] ;
        directions = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, dimensions}] ;
        Table[center + radius*direction/Sqrt[Total[direction^2]], {direction, directions}]
    ],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True},
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
] ; 


ClearAll[pointBoundingRegion] ;
Options[pointBoundingRegion] = {
    "NumberOfPoints" -> 16,           (* -- number of random points to generate on each ball *)
    "MaxNumberOfBalls" -> Infinity,   (* -- maximum number of balls for random points generation *)
    "NumberOfBalls" -> 1,             (* -- number of largest balls to select at each iteration *)
    "NumberOfIterations" -> 1         (* -- maximum number of itereatons to perform *)
} ;
pointBoundingRegion[   
    references_,                      (* -- reference points (points known to be inside the same cavity *)
    cloud_,                           (* -- clound points set *)
    options:OptionsPattern[]
] := Block[
    {lookup, cs, rs, cs$select, rs$select, cs$append, rs$append, points},
    lookup = Nearest[cloud] ;
    cs = references ;
    rs = Map[Norm, lookup[references]] ;
    Do[
        select = RandomSample[Range[Length[cs]], Min[Length[cs], OptionValue["MaxNumberOfBalls"]]] ;
        cs$select = cs[[select]] ;
        rs$select = rs[[select]] ;
        points = Flatten[generateRandomPointsOnNBall[OptionValue["NumberOfPoints"], cs$select, rs$select], 1] ;
        points = Pick[points, Table[UnsameQ[1, Total[Boole[isPointInsideNBall[point, cs, rs]]]], {point, points}], False] ;
        {cs$append, rs$append} = Transpose[Take[Reverse[SortBy[Transpose[{points, Map[Norm, points - Flatten[lookup[points, 1], 1]]}], Last]], Min[Length[points], OptionValue["NumberOfBalls"]]]] ;
        cs = Join[cs, cs$append] ;
        rs = Join[rs, rs$append] ;
        , OptionValue["NumberOfIterations"]
    ] ;
    {cs, rs}
] ;

Example-2D:
d = 2 ;
n = 10^5 ;
m = 100 ;
{points, region} = generateFakeData[d, n, m] ;

{cs, rs} = pointBoundingRegion[
    {{0., 0.}}, 
    points, 
    "NumberOfPoints" -> 16, 
    "NumberOfIterations" -> 128, 
    "NumberOfBalls" -> 1, 
    "MaxNumberOfBalls" -> 16
]  ;

regions = MapThread[Ball, {cs, rs}] ;

plot = Show[
    Map[RegionPlot, regions],
    ListPlot[points,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Blue],
    ListPlot[cs,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Black],
    PlotRange->All,
    ImageSize -> 600
]


Example-2D (real):
points = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kctdnf5ike59xvyfb7ywu/data.csv?rlkey=jm1vn7qqqtlk3geurkgr1u1zu&st=0ljvl2z4&dl=1", "CSV"] ;
{cs, rs} = pointBoundingRegion[{{0., 0.}}, points, "NumberOfPoints" -> 8, "NumberOfIterations" -> 128, "NumberOfBalls" -> 1, "MaxNumberOfBalls" -> 16]  ; // AbsoluteTiming
regions = MapThread[Ball, {cs, rs}] ;
plot = Show[
    Map[RegionPlot, regions],
    ListPlot[points,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Blue],
    ListPlot[cs,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Black],
    PlotRange->{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    ImageSize -> 600
]


Example-3D (a bit unsettling imagery):
d = 3 ;
n = 10^5 ;
m = 100 ;
{points, region} = generateFakeData[d,n,m] ;

{cs, rs} = pointBoundingRegion[{{0., 0., 0.}}, points, "NumberOfPoints" -> 8, "NumberOfIterations" -> 256, "NumberOfBalls" -> 1, "MaxNumberOfBalls" -> 16]  ; // AbsoluteTiming
regions = MapThread[Ball, {cs, rs}] ;
plot = Show[
    Map[RegionPlot3D[#, PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.25]]] &, regions],
    ListPointPlot3D[points,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.25]]],
    PlotRange->All,
    ImageSize -> 600
]


Original
Here is my solution that seems to work in 2D, but is slow and fails in 3D with DiscretizeRegion::drf. It is based on region union of balls iteratively generated on the region boundary.
It it possible to improve performance and extend to 3D and 4D?
ClearAll[generateFakeData];
generateFakeData[d_, n_, m_] := Block[
    {points, region},
    points = RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, {n, d}] ;
    region = ConvexHullRegion[RandomSample[points, m]] ;
    points = RandomReal[{-1.0, 1.0}, {n, d}] ;
    points = Select[points, Not @* RegionMember[region]];
    {points, region}
];

ClearAll[pointBoundingRegion] ;
Options[pointBoundingRegion] = {
    "NumberOfSamples" -> 256,          (* -- number of random samples to generate on the boundary at each iteration *)
    "NumberOfIterations" -> 1,         (* -- number of iterations *)
    "NumberOfBalls" -> 1,              (* -- number of largest balls to attach *)
    "MaxCellMeasure" -> Automatic      
} ;
pointBoundingRegion[   
    point_,                             (* -- reference point *)
    bounds_,                            (* -- bounding hyperbox *)
    cloud_,                             (* -- cloud *)
    options:OptionsPattern[]
] := Block[
    {region, boundary, points, nearest, balls},
    
    (* Initial region  *)
    region = Ball[point, Norm[Nearest[cloud, point]]] ;

    (* Main loop *)
    Do[
        (* Get current region boundary *)
        boundary = RegionBoundary[region] ;

        (* Generate random points on the boundary *)
        points = RandomPoint[boundary, OptionValue["NumberOfSamples"]] ;

        (* Locate corresponding nearest points *)
        nearest = Flatten[Nearest[cloud, #, 1] & /@ points, 1] ;

        (* Generate boundary balls *)
        balls = Take[Reverse[SortBy[MapThread[Ball[#, EuclideanDistance@##] &, {points, nearest}], Last]], OptionValue["NumberOfBalls"]] ;

        (* Add balls *)
        region = Fold[
            DiscretizeRegion[# , bounds, MaxCellMeasure -> OptionValue["MaxCellMeasure"]] & @* RegionUnion, 
            region, 
            balls
        ] ;    

        (* Continue *)
        , OptionValue["NumberOfIterations"]
    ] ;

    (* Return *)
    region
] ;

Example-1:
d = 2 ;
n = 10000 ;
m = 100 ;
{points, region} = generateFakeData[d, n, m] ;
region = pointBoundingRegion[{0., 0.}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, points, "NumberOfSamples" -> 32, "NumberOfIterations" -> 8, "NumberOfBalls" -> 8] ;
plot = Show[
    RegionPlot[region],
    ListPlot[points,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Blue],
    PlotRange->All,
    ImageSize -> 800
]


Example-2:
data = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kctdnf5ike59xvyfb7ywu/data.csv?rlkey=jm1vn7qqqtlk3geurkgr1u1zu&st=0ljvl2z4&dl=1", "CSV"] ;
region = pointBoundingRegion[{0., 0.}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, data, "NumberOfSamples" -> 32, "NumberOfIterations" -> 16, "NumberOfBalls" -> 16] ;
plot = Show[
    RegionPlot[region],
    ListPlot[data,AspectRatio->1,PlotStyle->Blue],
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> 800
]


Example-3 (fails in 3D):
d = 3 ;
n = 10000 ;
m = 100 ;
{points, region} = generateFakeData[d,n,m] ;
region = pointBoundingRegion[{0., 0., 0.}, {{-1,1}, {-1,1}, {-1,1}}, points, "NumberOfSamples" -> 32, "NumberOfIterations" -> 1, "NumberOfBalls" -> 2] ;
Show[
    RegionPlot3D[region, PlotStyle->Directive[LightGray, Opacity[0.5]]], 
    ListPointPlot3D[points, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Blue],
    PlotRange -> All
]
(* DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region BooleanRegion[ ... *)

